# How do I get out of this mess caused by power failure while upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10?

Tags: upgrade, 11.10, dpkg

When my battery died during a release upgrade and I started it again, it showed me a scan disc check screen. After which, it returned the black screen of before.

I pressed all the function keys one after the other then ran my hand all over the keyboard.

I am not sure what particular key triggered a 'DOS looking' log in screen. I entered my old username and password and it brought me to a 'terminal like' interface.

I ran

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and it returned

```
dpkg was interrupted you must manually run 'dpkg -- configure - a'
```

How to manually run 'dpkg --configure -a'???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: dpkg was interrupted... run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resume a release upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

Just run `dpkg --configure -a`, this will run the dpkg software with the --configure and -a parameters which will fix your system.

Just type `dpkg --configure -a` at the command-line, just as you did when you typed `sudo apt-get upgrade`.