# E: dpkg was interrupted... run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'

Tags: dpkg

I was running an upgrade with the apt-get command, and it was taking an exceptionally long time because half way through my ISP hit me in the face with their fair usage policy.

After sitting outside & watching the rain for awhile my electronics regained consciousness, so I went back to complete the upgrade and my terminal scolds me with

```
"E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem."
```

The last bit of legible info was all this:

```
Installing (ri/RDoc) documention for (stuff and such)
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'watobo-0.9.8.724.gem' (>= 0) in any repository
rm: cannot remove `watobo-0.9.8.724.gem': No such file or directory

Setting up metasploit (4.3.0-bt1) ...
Upgrading Pre-Existing Installation...
/opt/metasploit/postgresql/scripts/ctl.sh : postgresql  (pid 1191) already running
prosvc is running
metasploit is running
[*]
[*] Attempting to update the Metasploit Framework...
[*]
```

So on it goes for miles, talking about gem caches, rubies, & stuff I wish I had. All up until:

```
A    lib/gemcache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/state_machine-1.1.2/gemfiles/active_record-2.1.2.gemfile.lock
```

...and there it has sat, all night.
   If I stop it, will I still get the dpkg error (on the off chance that I won't), or if so what do I need to to resume using apt-get commands and its Super Cow Powers?

Answer (score 103):

> ```
> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
> ```

This error is actually telling you exactly what is wrong: `dpkg` was interrupted as a result the package was not configured correctly.

Run the command it tells you to `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it should be able to correct itself.

If it doesn't try running `sudo apt-get install -f` (to fix broken packages) and then try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` again.

Just make sure you have internet access available so that you can download any dependencies.

These instructions may not work if by upgrade you meant `apt-get dist-upgrade` if you were trying to do a distribution upgrade (e. g. 11.10 → 12.04) then you will need to edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: i have done the same but it did not worked check this one http://askubuntu.com/questions/469553/how-to-install-flash-plugin-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64-bit-version

Comment: running the dpkg command fixed the issue for me. i think there was some issue with rolling back from the 4.8 kernel to 4.4, there was a whole run of version sanity checks in the middle of configuration.

Comment: running  "apt-get install -f" also gives me the "dpkg was interrupted" message...

Comment: For me this results in the package that broke in the first place, attempting to install and thus causing the OS to hang.

Comment: Nice. Worked for me somehow.

Comment: This is getting really predictable… This brings me back to the original error. Typing in the command ‘dpkg —configure –a’ leads it to sit and freeze for a while, after which it asks for my password, and after that, no matter what I try to do it tells me I need to run… Wait for it… the command ‘dpkg —configure –a’. Apt-get install -f Also only gives that same exact error. And stack exchange maintains its apparently 100% unbroken track record of “solutions” that lead to absolutely nothing but the original error that you were trying to fix by using them! Woohoo!

Answer (score 18):

I tried the solution of @TrailRider and didn't work for me.
I solve it doing the following:

1. Delete the updates with:

   ```
   cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates

   sudo rm *
   ```
2. Tried to update and upgrade:

   ```
   sudo apt update

   sudo apt upgrade
   ```
3. I couldn't, it says that:

   ```
   E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock
   ```

   This means that some program is updating the system or installing a new software.
4. **IMPORTANT**: Check if some other process is locking `dpkg` files instead of deleting them immediately. Because if that is the case, you should wait for them to finish.
5. Checking if some programs is locking `dpkg` files:

   ```
   ps aux | grep -i apt
   ```

   If you have only one output, something that finishes like:

   ```
   S+   19:16   0:00 grep --color=auto -i apt
   ```

   you are lucky. You could delete the `dpkg` lock files which you can double-check manually one by one with:

   ```
   sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
   sudo lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
   sudo lsof /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
   ```

   To delete them use:

   ```
   sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
   sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
   sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
   ```
6. Try again:

   ```
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```

   It should work.
7. You should try to recover whatever you were installing at that moment with:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

   This should resume the process and keep everything stable.

That is how I fix it.

**NOTE**: I recommend you whatever you try to keep of track/log of what commands are you applying, this precaution will help other to help you if something goes wrong.

Comment: Please consider a title OP from me, cause you saved my laptop stuck after upgrade 20.04.1 stuck for a week.

Comment: Thank you so so so so much!!!..it worked....I had to kill the process running in the background first which I was able to see using your suggestion `ps aux | grep -i apt` ..it showed me two process so I killed the first one and kept `S+   19:16   0:00 grep --color=auto -i apt` , then I followed everything as you said

Answer (score 0):

Boot to the GRUB menu, choose *Advanced options for Ubuntu*, and select the second option (the option that has *(recovery mode)* at the end). Then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to correct the problem. The following detailed instructions describe how to do this  step-by-step.

---

#### Boot into recovery mode

Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

The timing when to press the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key can be tricky, so sometimes if you miss it you need to try it again. If that doesn't work try the answers to [I can't get the GRUB menu to show up during boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/87409/). Then runsudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

You will see a GNU GRUB menu screen that looks like this. Select **Advanced options for Ubuntu** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

A new purple screen will appear showing a list of kernels, which includes options of booting the kernels normally or in recovery mode.

[image]

Press the down arrow key until you select the **2nd entry from the top** (the one with the **recovery mode in the description**) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice.

Now you should see this recovery menu:

[image: recovery menu]

Using the arrow keys scroll down to **network** (the third entry from the bottom in the Recovery Menu) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Using the arrow keys scroll down to **root** (the second entry from the bottom in the Recovery Menu) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should now see a root prompt and you can run commands from it.

#### Run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Run the following commands.

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
fsck -f /
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```