# How to resolve E: Internal Error when using apt-get remove?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I use:

```
apt-get remove
```

To remove some software, but it displays:

```
error:E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0 .
```

I also try this to resolve the error:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/102991621/libssl1.0.0_1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.5_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.5_i386.deb
```

But it also gives an error :

```
 libssl1.0.0:i386 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4.5 cannot be configured because libssl1.0.0:amd64 is in a different version (1.0.1-4ubuntu5.3)
```

I want know the correct way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 23):

For me this works:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Src: [E: dpkg was interrupted... run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a)

Reboot then,

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

I hope it works for you too!

Comment: Worked for me. The installation of an update was interrupted by a full disk and after making room 'dpkg --configure -a' was enough to continue the installation.

Answer (score 7):

I also encountered this error on Ubuntu 12.04. I fixed it with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: installing all packages in /var/cache/apt/archives is dangerous and unnecessary.

Comment: might be dangerous but it worked like a charm. Thank you Eliah Kagan and user80001.
 I sure hope this dependancy hell with multiarch get's solved quickly. This is the second system that has been hosed by this problem and cost me several valueable hours to fix.

Comment: remember that with multi-arch all arches of the same package must be the same version.

Comment: Worked for me too. And I don't think installing all packages from that directory is dangerous in this case. The apt-get clean takes care of that.

Comment: `dpkg: error: cannot access archive '/var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 7):

use dpkg -i on both of these:

```
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.3_i386.deb
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.3_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem stemmed from an unmet dependency for rhythmbox. Just the following 3 commands got rid of the dependency and error. These are from a previous posting.

```
error: E: Internal Error, No file name for libssl1.0.0
```

I just entered

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Answer (score 0):

If the suggestion

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

does not work for you, try to reinstall both packages `libssl1.0.0:i386` and `libssl1.0.0:amd64`. You might have to force this because you temporarily break dependencies until these packages will have been reinstalled with the fourth of the followting command:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends libssl1.0.0:i386
sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends libssl1.0.0:amd64
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```