# Error when installing vsftpd

Tags: 14.04, cloud, vsftpd

I was trying to install the vsftpd ftp server but get this error:

```
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/vsftpd not found.
dpkg: error processing package vsftpd (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status
100 Errors were encountered while processing:
  vsftpd E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

To install it I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in a virtual machine in Cloud9 virtual service.

And here is the output for the command `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall vsftpd`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libck-connector0 ncurses-term openssh-sftp-server ssh-import-id
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 87 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for vsftpd:amd64
```

The output of `sudo dpkg --configure vsftpd` is:

```
Setting up vsftpd (3.0.2-1ubuntu2.14.04.1) ...
vsftpd user (ftp) already exists, doing nothing.

vsftpd directory (/srv/ftp) already exists, doing nothing.
invoke-rc.d: unknown initscript, /etc/init.d/vsftpd not found.
dpkg: error processing package vsftpd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 100
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vsftpd
```

The output of `dpkg-query -s vsftpd` is:

```
Package: vsftpd
Status: deinstall ok half-configured
Priority: extra
Section: net
Installed-Size: 353
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 3.0.2-1ubuntu2.14.04.1
Replaces: ftp-server
Provides: ftp-server
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) | file-rc (>= 0.8.16), libc6 (>= 2.15), libcap2 (>= 2.10), libpam0g (>= 0.99.7.1), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0), libwrap0 (>= 7.6-4~), adduser, libpam-modules, netbase
Recommends: logrotate
Conflicts: ftp-server
Conffiles:
 /etc/systemd/system/vsftpd.service 15767a25695a9f148e9feb731c5a1f0b
 /etc/vsftpd.conf b95bd4eef05d8db3a7f0e494723dae21
 /etc/logrotate.d/vsftpd dac2cb7b9cfd8a03b4fa9ca3601a43a6
 /etc/init/vsftpd.conf 4dcef85ff33f31f1f486865a94d800e8
 /etc/pam.d/vsftpd e75200b7896d8b2c2f2590d0e3d4a6ef
 /etc/ftpusers 839f3157aad792bafbbdcd932a95a345
Description: lightweight, efficient FTP server written for security
 This package provides the "Very Secure FTP Daemon", written from
 the ground up with security in mind.
 .
 It supports both anonymous and non-anonymous FTP access, PAM authentication,
 bandwidth limiting, and the Linux sendfile() facility.
Homepage: http://vsftpd.beasts.org/
Original-Maintainer: Daniel Baumann <daniel.baumann@progress-technologies.net>
```

And the file `/etc/init.d/vsftpd` not exists in my system.

Comment: Could you please include the full output of `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall vsftpd` so we can get the full picture?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I add the output from `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall vsftpd` to the question.

Comment: Better formatting of the original `apt-get` error message brought me more insight. What's the output of `sudo dpkg --configure vsftpd`? That might provide more details as to why the post-installation script failed. I'm also interested in whether `/etc/init.d/vsftpd` actually exists, and the details of the installed package (output of `dpkg-query -s vsftpd`).

Comment: @DavidFoerster I update again the question with the outputs that you request.

Comment: `/etc/init.d/vsftpd` is no part of the [`vsftpd` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/amd64/vsftpd/filelist). In Trusty it uses the Upstart (`/etc/init/*.conf`) or the Systemd init system (`/etc/systemd/`) instead of the older System V init system (`/etc/init.d/*`) but something else is trying to refer to the latter. I would try to `apt-get purge` the package and then install it again.

Comment: `E: Internal Error, No file name for vsftpd:amd64` point to an error in Apt's package cache. You can purge the cache with `sudo apt-get clean`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix E: Internal Error, No file name for libc6](http://askubuntu.com/questions/266450/how-to-fix-e-internal-error-no-file-name-for-libc6)