# configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Tags: 14.04, apt, gcc

So I'm trying to install ruby but when I run `rbenv install -v 2.2.3` I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ruby-build.20161217084514.23075 ~
Downloading ruby-2.2.3.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.3.tar.bz2
/tmp/ruby-build.20161217084514.23075/ruby-2.2.3 /tmp/ruby-build.20161217084514.23075 ~
Installing ruby-2.2.3...
config.guess already exists
config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/ruby-build.20161217084514.23075/ruby-2.2.3':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20161121-14-gd799bdd)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20161217084514.23075
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20161217084514.23075.log

Last 10 log lines:
config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/ruby-build.20161217084514.23075/ruby-2.2.3':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

I'm not an expert but it looks like gcc might be missing I try installing gcc via `sudo apt-get install gcc` and I get the following error:

```
Setting up gcc (4:4.8.2-1ubuntu6) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/bin/gcc doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package gcc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 gcc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

then

```
sudo dpkg --purge gcc
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

But none of these worked. I think it might even be permission related, I recently had to restore /var/ and have had quite a few unrelated permissions/ownership errors since then. Any idea what's causing this?

EDIT:

When I run `update-alternatives --query cc` I get the following result:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for cc
```

When I run `ls -l /usr/bin/{cc,gcc}` here's what I get:

```
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  7  2014 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.8
```

Running `ls -ld /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/{,cc}` gives me:

```
ls: cannot access /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/cc: No such file or directory
drwxrwxr-x 2 mre mre 4096 Dec 17 00:06 /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/
```

From running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.8 gcc` I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,047 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for gcc:amd64
```

Then I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/337795/597617) answer and it worked so now gcc is compiling but when I run `rbenv install -v 2.2.3` I get this:

```
Last 10 log lines:
config.guess already exists
config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/ruby-build.20161217125354.10629/ruby-2.2.3':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: What are the outputs of `update-alternatives --query cc` and `ls -l /usr/bin/{cc,gcc}`?

Comment: I edited my question with the results to those

Comment: Thanks - the only way I can think that `/var` permissions might be involved is via the `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives` directory - it might also be helpful to see `ls -ld /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/{,cc}`

Comment: Added that to the edit as well

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure it explains the issue you're having, but I'd start by correcting those e.g. `sudo chown -R root:root /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/` ; `sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/` ; `sudo chmod 644 /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/*`

Comment: I tried changing those permissions and I got the same error after removing and installing gcc

Comment: Try reinstalling both `gcc` and the dependency `gcc-4.8` i.e. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcc-4.8 gcc`

Comment: I've updated the question with the updated info, gcc has been installed but I still can't install via rbenv

Comment: Is /tmp mounted with the `noexec` flag? Check the output of `mount`

Comment: so when I run `mount` nothing from /tmp is listed at all

Comment: In that case, /tmp is likely just a regular dir in / - we can probably forget that line of enquiry