# Upgrade to 18.04, now sudo apt-get upgrade produces loads of insserv errors as irqbalance is not configured

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

I've upgraded a virtual server (running on vmware) to 18.04 and now I get a lot of errors when I do `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-29-generic x86_64)

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-24 linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic linux-image-4.15.0-24-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-24-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-24-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up irqbalance (1.3.0-0.1) ...
insserv: Script eventlogd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script likewise is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwsmd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lsassd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwregd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script netlogond is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script dcerpcd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwiod is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script eventlogd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script likewise is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwsmd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lsassd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwregd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script netlogond is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script dcerpcd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwiod is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwsmd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script likewise is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwregd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script eventlogd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script netlogond is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lsassd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwiod is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script dcerpcd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwsmd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script likewise is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwregd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script eventlogd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script netlogond is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lsassd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwiod is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script dcerpcd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwsmd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script likewise is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwregd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script eventlogd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script netlogond is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lsassd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwiod is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script dcerpcd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwsmd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script likewise is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwregd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script eventlogd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script netlogond is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lsassd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwiod is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script dcerpcd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script eventlogd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script likewise is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwsmd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lsassd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwregd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script netlogond is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script dcerpcd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwiod is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'irqbalance' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `irqbalance'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `irqbalance'
insserv: Script lwregd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lwiod is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'atd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `atd'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `atd'
insserv: Script lwsmd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script lsassd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script eventlogd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script netlogond is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script likewise is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'screen-cleanup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `screen-cleanup'
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'apport' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `apport'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `apport'
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'nmbd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `nmbd'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `nmbd'
insserv: Script dcerpcd is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Provides:' entry: please add.
insserv: missing `Required-Start:' entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: script postgresql-8.3: service postgresql already provided!
insserv: script postgresql-8.3: service postgresql-8.3 already provided!
initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
insserv: warning: script 'smbd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `smbd'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `smbd'
update-rc.d: error: irqbalance Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
dpkg: error processing package irqbalance (--configure):
 installed irqbalance package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 irqbalance
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I repair it?

Comment: Try this: `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Somehow there is one package (`irqbalance`) not yet completely configured.

Comment: Hi Jos, thanks. That gave me this:
 user11@host11:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for user11:
Setting up irqbalance (1.3.0-0.1) ...
...
...
...
...
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 irqbalance

Comment: It looks like `irqbalance` was downloaded with empty script files (`missing` this and that). Perhaps doing `sudo apt install --reinstall irqbalance` may help.

Comment: Thanks but it gave me this Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-24 linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic linux-image-4.15.0-24-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-24-generic linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-24-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for irqbalance:amd64

Comment: Perhaps the first (but unaccepted) answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167784/how-to-resolve-e-internal-error-when-using-apt-get-remove) will help. At this point, it is safe to reboot.

Comment: rebooted, apt-get update, then hit the same apt-get upgrade issue, then the same error when --reinstall irqbalance.

Comment: Can you try removing `irqbalance` (which, as far as I can tell, doesn't have anything depending on it)? Try using `apt remove irqbalance -s` to simulate removal and see what will happen. If nothing awful appears like removing `ubuntu-desktop` go ahead and try `sudo apt remove irqbalance`. If it fails, try it with the lower level package manager `sudo dpkg --purge irqbalance`. If that works, run `sudo apt update` to see if it comes out clean or if there's an underlying problem. You can reinstall `irqbalance` if all is well...

Comment: Thanks Zanna, that uninstall did it. If I try to install irqbalance I get the error so I'll let it be uninstalled

Comment: OK, good news, thanks for adding your solution as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt remove irqbalance
```

That command did remove the errors and I'm satisfied. Thanks everyone involved.

Comment: If the problem is reproducible, consider filing a bug against the `irqbalance` package. It's supposed to work out-of-the-box.