# apache2 gives me an error code

Tags: apache2

after apache2 installation, apache doesn't work:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; disabled; vendor   preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-09-24 07:44:35 CEST;  30min ago

de set. 24 07:44:35 dai-Aspire-M7811 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP  Server...
de set. 24 07:44:35 dai-Aspire-M7811 apachectl[14153]: /usr/sbin /apachectl: 174: /usr/sbin/apachectl: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found
de set. 24 07:44:35 dai-Aspire-M7811 apachectl[14153]: Action 'start'  failed.
de set. 24 07:44:35 dai-Aspire-M7811 apachectl[14153]: The Apache error  log may have more information.
de set. 24 07:44:35 dai-Aspire-M7811 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control   process exited, code=exited status=127
de set. 24 07:44:35 dai-Aspire-M7811 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
de set. 24 07:44:35 dai-Aspire-M7811 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Can you help me? 
Thanks

PD: I removed apache2 and reinstalled it but it gives me an error code:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Hello, please, expand the terminal window before the copy and copy the entire lines, then [edit] and update your question.

Comment: For some reason the Apaches binary is not available: `/usr/sbin/apache2: not found`. So try to reinstall it: `sudo apt install --reinstall apache2`.

Comment: I did it and now gives another error:     E: Internal Error, No file name for apache2:amd64

Comment: Try this solution https://askubuntu.com/q/167784/566421

Answer (score 3):

I tried this and it worked fine:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2*
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Thanks pa4080!