# Unable to reinstall python-cryptography in Synaptic

Tags: 18.04

It returned an error:

```
E: Internal Error, No file name for python-cryptography:amd64
```

I tried to  run follow command and follow instruction from here [How to resolve E: Internal Error when using apt-get remove?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167784/how-to-resolve-e-internal-error-when-using-apt-get-remove?rq=1)

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

but it doesn't work, the terminal returned another error:

```
dpkg: Error handling package python-gi (--configure):

The software package is in a very unstable state.

You'd better reinstall it before configuring it.

Errors occur during processing:

Python-gi
```

according to this error  I try to use follow command to solve it:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python-gi
```

but same error appear again.
I am new to ubuntu, I dont know what should I do, if anyone can help me?Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve E: Internal Error when using apt-get remove?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167784/how-to-resolve-e-internal-error-when-using-apt-get-remove)

Comment: @user3140225 I has tried the approach of question you signed duplicate. But it seems it is not the same problem.

Comment: Perhaps you may have better luck with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/510830/618353). Make sure you adapt it to your case, that is for `pyhton-gi` and `python-cryptography`.

Comment: thank u, I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by following command:

```
sudo apt-get -m --reinstall install python python-minimal
```