# Computer won't recognize me typing password

Tags: wireless, drivers

I installed Linux OS 4 and while it was doing its first update the laptop went into stand by. When I closed it and I opened the computer again it caused me to think the computer was off but it was just in standby. So I turned it off while it was installing the updates.

When I turned it back on the Wifi and touchpad didn't work. I have to use a physical mouse for it to work.

I looked around a little and found a possible command for solving this:

[E: dpkg was interrupted... run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a)

But when I enter the command in the terminal it asks for:

```
[sudo] password for admin:
```

When I try to put my password in, the computer won't recognize that I am typing it.

Comment: generally the questions here need to pertain to Ubuntu. When you type your password you will not see anything in the terminal. Just type your password and hit enter.

Comment: Possible Duplicate:
[Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](http://askubuntu.com/q/112069/114818).

Comment: What is "Linux OS 4", please?

Comment: [Linux OS4](http://www.os4online.com/) is not an official [Ubuntu derivative](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives) as defined in the [faq](http://askubuntu.com/faq) so is off topic here.  In most versions of Unix and Linux however there is no feedback just type your password and press enter.  Nothing changes on the screen when you type and you will get an error message if you have mistyped it.

Answer (score 2):

To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use `sudo <command>`
and enter your password. **You won't get any visual feedback**; it is meant to be that way, as a security feature.

See `man sudo_root` for details.