# Dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg-configure-a' to correct the problem

Tags: update-manager

I was updating from 11.04 to 12.04 and I got this message:

```
Dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg-configure-a' to correct the problem
```

now I can't connect to the net nor can I use a cursor on my laptop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: dpkg was interrupted... run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a) and [How to start Ubuntu in Console mode](https://askubuntu.com/q/859630/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resume a release upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

Do as I exactly said.

After you power on your PC and coming to login screen of Ubuntu. press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> , It will directs you to a CLI screen then login there with your username and password. Then run as

```
sudo dpkg-configure-a
```

Comment: The screen just goes blank, is there anything else I can do