# Cannot install or update through Terminal Get this Error (in the body of question)

Tags: command-line, 13.10

Everything was working fine but now every-time I run sudo apt-get install (program) or even sudo apt-get update I get this message:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

what must I do to fix this? I am running Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got this error

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

suddenly run this command,

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

And then try to update or install packages.

Comment: I would accept this if it would let me but the time limit is too long. Just wondering why was this happening in the first place?

Comment: is your problem like this http://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a