# how to install flash plugin on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit version

Tags: package-management, dpkg, video, flash

When I play online videos, they are often interrupted with many blinks and other disturbances. Many times I was shown an error message that the flash player crashed. When I tried to install the flash plugin on the command line, this error was displayed. Can anyone help me to get out of this conflict?

```
$ sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
[sudo] password for agha:
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' 
 to correct the problem
```

Here’s a full log:

```
Ign http://in.archive.ubunutu.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubunutu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubunutu.com trusty-backports/main Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubunutu.com trusty-backports/multiverse Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubunutu.com trusty-backports/restricted Translation-en_IN
Ign http://in.archive.ubunutu.com trusty-backports/universe Translation-en_IN
Fetched 964 kB in 42s (22.4 kB/s)
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
agha@agha-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
agha@agha-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
agha@agha-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [(E: dpkg was interrupted... run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'...)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it should be able to correct itself.

or else

`sudo apt-get install -f` (fix broken packages) and then try running  `sudo dpkg --configure -a`  again.

You see how to install flash player in Ubuntu form following link
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Flash-Player-on-Ubuntu

Updated Answer :

dpkg is locked, try the following solution and follow the above (link) steps to install flash palyer.

[Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: it all goes in vain i have tried it and it shows the following error as displayed in my edited question

Comment: Did you try again since your last post? The logs seem to suggest that the cache is locked, like what would happen if you say have Synaptic open.

Comment: i did'nt get you mr biswas you mean i should try it once again

Comment: it's done mr.biswas thankyou verymuch

Answer (score 15):

The following works for me! I was trying to install the wireless driver when this error came. Had to delete the files and also the lock files.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
cd /var/lib/dpkg/updates
sudo rm *
sudo apt-get update
```

and then you can run your `apt-get install` to whatever package you want to install

Comment: +1 Just coming across this as the only working answer for me. Happened on a fresh install of 12.04 :D lol (love my old IBM).

Comment: Man, you saved my life.

Comment: Thank you. For me it worked to remove the locks and updates and then do "dpkg --configure -a"