# Tried to install Paper desktop theme but it froze my computer

Tags: gnome, themes

I'm running Gnome shell on my laptop that has Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to install the Paper desktop theme.

https://snwh.org/paper/download

Everything was going well until I got to

```
sudo apt-get install paper-icon-theme
```

That's where it froze my computer for an hour and my laptop ran out of battery (forgot my charger). When I tried to run it again I got the message

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to correct the problem.

I don't know what to do here. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` as the error suggested?

Comment: Open up the Terminal application and type in the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and let us know if that fixes the problem. Do you get further errors? What are they?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: dpkg was interrupted... run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a)

Comment: I tried 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' and it just froze again. Can I just delete what was installed? This is just becoming too bothersome and I think this bad install is freezing my computer as well. I've been trying to work on my laptop and it's been freezing at random times.

Comment: It finally went through without freezing. But I got this error instead

Comment: gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: **
Gtk:ERROR:/build/gtk+3.0-3sSotQ/gtk+3.0-3.10.8/./gtk/updateiconcache.c:1117:write_bucket: assertion failed: (*offset == ftell (cache))
Aborted (core dumped)
WARNING: icon cache generation failed for /usr/share/icons/Paper

Comment: Do you already have Unity Tweak Tool installed? Are you able to install it if not? Can you choose the Unity Desktop from the login menu and run a session using the Unity Desktop instead of Gnome Desktop? Does your laptop experience the same 'random freezing' if you try running a Unity session? Just a few things you can try whilst waiting for a better answer than mine -  I seem to remember having an irritating time when a laptop had an update interrupted by powering off and I think I ended up re-installing and starting again. I'm going to try and find some better suggestions for you first (!)

Comment: I have the Ubuntu Tweak and Gnome Tweak Tool. What I did was the Witiich's linked post method and I tried the rest of the command line that the Paper site provides. So far it seems to be working and my computer doesn't freeze anymore.

Comment: Good news. Glad it's back and running. I'll remove my answer. It was about removing the PPA you'd added and 'purging' the paper-icon-theme.