# Laptop doesn't boot. Many problems at the same time

Tags: boot, kubuntu, dpkg, lightdm

I'll start from the beginning. I had Ubuntu 16.04 working fine for quite a time. Everything was working fine (I had a problem, that i still have, while bios don't find any bootable drive. But then I get a list, select the main one, and boots). SO THAT'S NOT THE PROBLEM.

Yesterday I decided to install Steam, everything worked fine. But when the installation was done, I couldn't open any folder. It said paths weren't found. Neither opening "dolphin" worked. So I said "A reboot will fix it!". But the reboot were the end. Since that moment, I can't get my laptop to work. It starts as always, but when it gets to "Ubuntu Logo Screen", it gets stuck. Logo fading in and out forever. I tried to fix it in different ways. And I've come to this point:

I'm in the root konsole. I got here from "Recovery mode".

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do ou want to continue? [Y/n]
Setting up lightdm (1.10.6-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: eeror processing package lightdm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
 lightdm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then, I tried to purge and reinstall `lightdm` through:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge lightdm 
It works without problems. But then, sudo apt-get install lightdm pops out a screen of package configuration with two options: lightDM and lightdm. I've tried both, and both gave me 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lightdm
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

At some point, I also got `E: Package 'whatever i tried to install'` has no installation candidate.

I don't know what to do. At this point my laptop doesn't work at all. It's a Acer e5-571g-56t1

Comment: Although it is likely possible to save your installation, you should seriously consider the time cost. Since you still have the ability to get access to the filesystem, the quickest path to a working installation may be to backup your files and re-install.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is likely possible to save your installation, you should seriously consider the time cost. Since you still have the ability to get access to the filesystem, the quickest path to a working installation may be to backup your files and re-install.

If you do want to attempt to fix it (it would be a good learning experience) then please resubmit discrete questions. Looks like you have at least three areas to address (1) you have a package that is not fully installed, (2) either your grub configuration is wrong or your kernel is missing/broken, (3) something you did since yesterday broke your boot sequence, so you should discover what it was to avoid doing it again.

For (1), see [E: dpkg was interrupted... run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163200/e-dpkg-was-interrupted-run-sudo-dpkg-configure-a)

For (2), you will need to do some debugging to see what the issue is. Boot to the recovery shell (or preferably) to a live USB disk. From there you can check that the MBR (or UEFI) is pointing to Grub, that Grub is pointing to your kernel, and that your kernel parameters are pointing to your root filesystem. Until we get some more information, we won't know which is broken / how to fix it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelBoot

Answer (score 0):

This happens often if you have an nvidia driver and you do an upgrade. if so try reinstalling the nvidia driver.
for the /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error...try sudo dpkg --configure -a and then sudo apt-get install -f