# Resume upgrade to 13.10

Tags: unity, upgrade, 13.10

I had 13.04 and started to upgrade to 13.10. But the computer hanged and I rebooted it.

I did instructions from [How do I resume a release upgrade/update?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade-update)

Now OS launches, but I upgrade is incomplete: there is no panels in Unity (just a background with some files on Desktop). I think that some post-install scripts didn't launch.
Please help me with this trouble.

P.S. Or how can I completely reinstall unity (with all of the dependencies)? My be it helps.

```
ubuntu@ext:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=saucy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.10"
ubuntu@ext:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Answer (score 1):

PSA: Please do backups before upgrading. [How to back up my entire system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7809/how-to-back-up-a-system)

---

Even if your system says that you are already on 13.10, some packages may still not be configured and troubleshooting from the answer to that question might help: [How do I resume a release upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade-update)

If that doesn't work, you could try [this workaround from the german Ubuntuusers Wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Paketverwaltung/Problembehebung#Saemtliche-Pakete-neu-installieren), which saves a list of all currently installed packages and then reinstall them, that should give you a consistent system state.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep "\binstall" | awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/dpkg.log 
sudo xargs -n1 apt-get --reinstall install -y < /tmp/dpkg.log
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a script to do the upgrade from the command-line:

`$ do-release-upgrade`

It managed to resume a botched upgrade, when I had the same problem a while ago. It has to be run as superuser

Comment: It's already saucy. I've added console output.

Comment: let's hope someone else has a better idea ... .