# Ubuntu upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10 failed

Tags: upgrade

I updated the system using apt-get dist-upgrade and then I ran sudo update-manager -d to upgrade to wily werewolf but suddenly lights went off and my computer too.Now if apt-get update it is showing updates related to 15.10 and I am trying to use upgrade manager but it do not respond.How to revert my system back to where I upgraded using dist-upgrade and again be able to upgrade to 15.10.

[It hangs here on sudo update-manager -d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY4tc.png)

Comment: try http://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade

Comment: Removed all the third parties related to wily with help of softwares and updates and then apt-get update,Now I am able to upgrade again.Thanks