# Accidental shutdown during 14.04 -> 16.04 upgrade

Tags: 16.04

I absentmindedly shut down my machine during the upgrade. Now Linux gives me the login screen, and after that the home screen with no launcher icons some graphical glitches.

I believe booting from USB and trying to repair the install will fix the problem; is this correct? Or is there something I can do using the shell via Ctrl-Alt-F1 ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question and its accepted answer may be what you are looking for: [How do I resume a release upgrade?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands after you login :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

that should fix the broken packages if any