# Fix dpkg after interrupted do-release-upgrade

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, dpkg, do-release-upgrade

I recently was updating from 14.04 to 16.04 (via `do-release-upgrade`). Everything was going fine until it pulled up an `ncurses` dialogue for handling conflicting config files for "unattended upgrades" -- a dialogue which failed to respond to input (it froze).

Since there was no way to continue, I killed the process, leaving everything half upgraded. If I try to run `do-release-upgrade` again, it claims to already be version 16.04. I have not restarted the machine, as I don't know what would happen. If I run `apt-get -f dist-upgrade` it claims that every package I have is no longer needed, then tries to configure them all, failing because all of their dependencies are also not configured. Trying `dpkg --configure -a` gives the same configuring errors (ex. `389-ds depends on 389-admin; however:
  Package 389-admin is not configured yet.`)

[Output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23426060/)

Given all this, I still think there should be some way to recover, seeing as everything is still running (for the most part). The question is, what is that way?

Comment: [This might help](http://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade)

Answer (score 3):

Fix missing packages, type in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```