# Laptop Suspended During Upgrade to 17.10

Tags: upgrade, suspend

So my laptop suspended while performing the upgrade. When I woke it back up it went to the login screen, but for some reason, I can't type my password into the password box. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You session manager probably froze due to the upgrade. I you are still on the lock screen, you may try to switch to console with CTRL+ALT+F3.

In worth case, nothing is lost as you should able to resume the upgrade with the following process :

[How do I resume a release upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/how-do-i-resume-a-release-upgrade)

If you are unable to switch to terminal and force reboot is failing, you should be able to drop in rescue mode, and in worth case, you will need to boot from a live CD/USB and do the following process.

```
# Identify the partition where is installed your system
sudo fdisk -l

# Mount your partition (replace xx by the correct partition)
sudo mount /dev/sdxx /mnt

# Bind system directory
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/run

# Enter in chroot
chroot /mnt

# Fix potential installed package
sudo dpkg --configure -a

# Fix potential dependencies issues
sudo apt -f install

# Finalize the upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

After that, just close your terminal and restart your system, everything should be upgraded.