# 20.04 retains older 4.15 kernel and radeon drivers. How to upgrade from there?

Tags: kernel, radeon, 20.04

I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. LTS and the update-manager crashed with "Oh no. Something has gone wrong" in the process of upgrading. Through the terminal, I seemingly completed the upgrade [with the steps from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/346795/1071715) and can boot into the system fine now.

I found out that the kernel has not been updated and I'm still running on 4.15

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-96-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 1 03:25:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried to install the 5.4 kernel with

```
apt install linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic
```

which worked fine and I restarted the system. From there, I noticed the screen was in low resolution and `lshw -c video` did no longer use the radeon driver.

On 4.15, it uses the correct driver and all seems well:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/oliver# lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 80
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:141 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d07fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:dfe00000-dfe3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

How can I update to the newer kernel while retaining radeon graphics driver support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was implicitly resolved with the upgrade to 20.04.1, which introduced a newer kernel version. This will likely not help anyone stuck in that state, but on the other hand this likely will no longer occur with 20.04.01 out.