# Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 but retain specific kernel (4.9)

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, kernel, 20.04

My hardware has a dependency on kernel 4.9 and I would like to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04.  Is it possible to upgrade all the other components without upgrading the kernel?

I found this post that implies (by error) that it can be done.

[20.04 retains older 4.15 kernel and radeon drivers. How to upgrade from there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230162/20-04-retains-older-4-15-kernel-and-radeon-drivers-how-to-upgrade-from-there)

Comment: I am interested to know why you want to retain the kernel. Is there any driver issue with newer kernels?

Comment: Yes.  The kernel for the Amlogic S922X (Odroid N2 actually) isn't stable in mainline yet.  Getting close but no cigar!

Comment: You can add that info about your system in the question. That will also help other users who are using the same device.