# Updated to 20.04, no change in interface

Tags: updates, 20.04

I tried to upgrade ubuntu desktop to ubuntu 20.04 using the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` . Now the details option in settings, the sources in the repostories show that i am running ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa. But my desktop experience is exactly the same. No Apps have been changed. But now I can't update since it already is 20.04. Please Help

Comment: `lsb_release -a` Did the upgade get interrupted and what was the previous version?

Comment: Yes, the upgrade was interrupted, after which it said that all packages must be upgraded before upgrading. After upgrading running the command downloaded around another 10 mb of updates and said update was successful.

`lsb_release -a` returns the following :`
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu Focal Fossa (development branch)
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
`

Comment: The previous version was 19.04

Comment: [Does this help?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346678/)

Comment: I am afraid it does not. All my sources files have been updated to focal and `sudo apt upgrade` command had already upgraded to all the latest versions, So, no packages are broken. But it still runs the ubuntu 19 interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem was by going to 'Software and updates' and in the 'Updates' Tab, changing the 'Notify me...' option to 'For any new version'. Afterwards I ran `sudo apt dist-upgrade` which updated the OS. I let it run without any interruptions and my computer was updated to Ubuntu 20.04 completely.