# What do I do with an upgrade stalled at 15%? And How do I safely recover?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I finally upgraded my laptop from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS and it seems to have stalled at `Progress: 15%`. I was doing other things and periodically checking in on it, but the first few times my laptop when dark it continued with the upgrade.

This time it's been stalled for several hours and I think it's time to bail, but I'm not sure how to do that safely.

The most recent bit on the screen is this:

```
Reloading AppArmor profiles 
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
Setting up openssl (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf ...
Setting up ca-certificates (20210119~20.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Setting up libbsd0:amd64 (0.10.0-1) ...
Setting up libedit2:amd64 (3.1-20191231-1) ...
Setting up libcbor0.6:amd64 (0.6.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libfido2-1:amd64 (1.3.1-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libkrb5support0:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libk5crypto3:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libkeyutils1:amd64 (1.6-6ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (1.17-6ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up openssh-client (1:8.2p1-4ubuntu0.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/ssh/ssh_config ...
Removing obsolete conffile /etc/ssh/moduli ...
Setting up liblzo2-2:amd64 (2.10-2) ...
Setting up squashfs-tools (1:4.4-1) ...
Setting up libkmod2:amd64 (27-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up udev (245.4-4ubuntu3.4) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/init.d/udev ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/udev/udev.conf ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up snapd (2.48+20.04) ...
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
```

How do I safely bail out of an upgrade that I launched with `do-release-upgrade`?

I see that there are replies to older, similar questions but I don't want to assume that what worked in 2012 will still work today.

A few folks have asked if [What do I do with an upgrade stalled at 15%? And How do I safely recover?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314038/what-do-i-do-with-an-upgrade-stalled-at-15-and-how-do-i-safely-recover/1314073?noredirect=1#comment2236982_1314073) is a different question. It is different. I launched the upgrade with `do-release-upgrade`, I didn't launch it from the gui.

It sounds like I may need to kill this, boot into recovery mode, and start over from there, if it doesn't get any farther.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resume a release upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/q/346678/)

Comment: Is that still accurate? I'm still stalled, I haven't forced quit yet.

Comment: Yes, it should be. I am not sure how much of a functional system you might get after a reboot, I had to use the recovery mode to run those commands. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The `do-release-upgrade` process is running inside Screen session, so you can press <kbd>R</kbd> to restart it.

I tried this several times, it ends with normal upgrade.

To be completely sure use normally recommended commands after upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Just <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> ? In the terminal?

Comment: Only `r` without <Shift>. Maybe <Enter> afterwards.

Comment: It ticked up to 16% so something is still running.